# Find the distribution function of $Y=X_1+X_2$

Tags: probability-distributions

> Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two independent Poisson random variables parameter $\lambda$, find the distribution function of $Y=X_1+X_2$.

I'm not really sure how to find the probability density function.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Sums_of_independent_random_variables) for some useful information.

Comment: @William "Use the convolution formula for the sum of independent random variables with continuous distributions" What are you playing at? This suggestion was already offtopic when you posted it in an answer. Now that you deleted the answer after I posted a comment mentioning the point, you repost this still offtopic suggestion as a comment? Are you trying to mislead the OP?

Comment: @William And the "possible duplicate" you suggest is not a duplicate (did you actually read the other page?). Wow.

Comment: @William "No I did not read the other page" Let me suggest to change your modus operandi then.

Comment: http://www1.udel.edu/FREC/eggermont/Courses/Stat370/Poisson This gives a nice, thorough outline of the proof that makes sure to explain all of the steps while not being too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides convolution, we can also use moment generating function to find the distributions.

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} \left[ \exp(tY) \right]&=\mathbb{E} \left[ \exp(t(X_1+X_2)) \right]\\ &=\mathbb{E}\left[ \exp \left( tX_1 \right) \exp \left(tX_2 \right) \right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[ \exp \left( tX_1 \right)\right] \mathbb{E} \left[ \exp \left(tX_2 \right) \right] \\
&=\exp(\lambda (e^t-1) )\exp(\lambda (e^t-1) )\\
&= \exp(2\lambda (e^t-1) )
\end{align}

Hence $Y$ follows Poisson distribution of parameter $2 \lambda$.